# Using delegates in C# .Net, what happens when I run out of threads in the .Net threadpool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates, threadpool

I'm making a multi-threaded application using delegates to handle the processing of requests in a WCF service. I want the clients to be able to send the request and then disconnect and await for a callback to announce the work is done (which will most likely be searching through a database). I don't know how many requests may come in at once, it could be one every once in a while or it could spike to dozens.

As far as I know, .Net's threadpool has 25 threads available to use. What happens when I spawn 25 delegates or more? Does it throw an error, does it wait, does it pause an existing operation and start working on the new delegate, or some other behavior?

Beyond that, what happens if I want to spawn up to or more than 25 delegates while other operations (such as incoming/outgoing connections) want to start, and/or when another operation is working and I want to spawn another delegate?

I want to make sure this is scalable without being too complex.

Thanks

Comment: If you use WCF then you don't have the 2.0 RTM version of .NET.  The limit is 250 x number of CPU cores.

Comment: What I mean about being concerned about threads (and how I'm accessing them) is calling normally-synchronous methods through a delegate using BeginInvoke. Most likely the performance bottlenecks will be the responder client doing its thing (waiting on a database search) and then, possibly, returning a large amount of data and the time it takes to send that across the internet to the central broker service and then back to the requesting client.

Comment: I am currently developing this in .Net 3.5, though I may move to 4.0 if it looks like it offers features/performance I need for my application (and WCF specifically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All operations are queued (I am assuming that you are using the threadpool directly or indirectly). It is the job of the threadpool to munch through the queue and dispatch operations onto threads. Eventually all threads may become busy, which will just mean that the queue will grow until threads are free to start processing queued work items.

Comment: I'm calling BeginInvoke from a delegate pointing to a method. (My knowledge of multithreading is very limited. I have read quite a bit in the last week and know how to implement my objective in various ways, but I don't fully comprehend or understand to implications of doing so, and delegates seem like the easiest way to make the process asynchronous).

Comment: @Chris Calling BeginInvoke will indeed be using the ThreadPool indirectly. All operations are queued, and available threads take items from the queue. If there are no available threads, the queue grows until there are. It is scalable and means that clients are not blocked even if all threads are busy - the queue is the key part of the design here.

Comment: Although it sounds like the system handles this (but to be sure); Do I need to design/implement my own queue, or will the system naturally queue my operations (fire and forget)?

Comment: @Chris The ThreadPool will handle queuing aspects for you, it is a fundamental part of its capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing delegates with threads, and number of concurrent connections.

With WCF 2-way bindings, the connection remains open while waiting for the callback.
IIS 7 or above, on modern hardware should have no difficulty maintaining a few thousand concurrent connections if they're sitting idle.

Delegates are just method pointers - you can have as many as you wish. That doesn't mean they're being invoked concurrently.

Comment: I'm running the services as stand along to take advantage of the NetTCP binding and having access to callbacks without relying on the DualHttp binding. I'm calling the delegates with BeginInvoke from within the WCF methods so the client and service can end the current operation as quickly as possible, which as I understand, passes it off to another thread (thus making it essentially multithreaded). Unless I am mistaken on how the whole thing works, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` then it just queues the extra items until a thread is available.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPools default max amount of thread is 250 not 25! You can still set a higher limit for the ThreadPool if you need that.
If your ThreadPool runs out of threads two things may happen: All opperations are queued until the next resource is available. If there are finished threads those might still be "in use" so the GC will trigger and free up some of them, providing you with new resources.
However you can also create Threads not using the ThreadPool.

Comment: Although in the long run we may have a need for a huge number of concurrent threads and connections, most likely we will only have a few clients ever accessing our central service (much less all at once). However, it does need to scale to that ("just in case").